# how to pass function data to blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function I created in my Blade view that returns data from an API. How do I pass that data as a value to an HTML input field?

My inline php code:

```
@php
    function getPrice()
    {
        $url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        foreach($json as $obj)
        {
            if($obj->code == 'USD')
            $btc = $obj->rate;
        }
        echo $btc;
    }
@endphp
```

The HTML input field I want to pass this data above to:

```
 <p class="form-group"> 
    <label for="subject">Amount in BTC<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <i class="fa fa-btc "></i> 
  <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="btc" id="btc" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount in Bitcoin" readonly="true" >
</p>
```

Comment: You should write all business logic in the controller and not in the view file, else you are defeating the purpose of using MVC.

Comment: That's what I'm about to say. MVC is created to organize programmers lives:)

Comment: MVC is all the way made for the purpose of keeping your logical code and your views individually so that you can manage everything very easily. your are going out of track from MVC. try to follow it. you can then manage your code easily and you will know what you are going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need `function()`?
You can simply leave:

```
@php
    $btc = null; (?)
    $url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    foreach($json as $obj)
    {
        if($obj->code == 'USD')
            $btc = $obj->rate;
    }
@endphp
```

And after:

```
<input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="{{ $btc }}" name="btc" id="btc" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount in Bitcoin" readonly="true" >
```

Comment: php ... endphp should be before the input

Answer (score 0):

I've updated this post. You don't need to create a function. Neither echo the variable. Just like this:

```php
<?php              
    $url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    foreach($json as $obj){
        if($obj->code == 'USD')
        {
            $btc = $obj->rate;
        }
    }
?>
```

And assuming both codes are in same blade file. You just call the variable like this:

```html
 <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="btc" id="btc" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount in Bitcoin" readonly="true" value = "{{$btc}}" >
```

Comment: However. This is not a good idea. It should be in the controller.

Comment: yes i know... but it is allowed. however what i'm really trying to do is perform a mathematical calculation from two selected option in the view divided by this $btc variable and output the result in the read-only input tag above. how do i go about this